# get href path from <a> attribute and pass to next html page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have two links:

```
<div class="holder_content1" id="link" >   
<p> <a href="PDFJS/pdfFile/Tut02_v2-Ans.pdf"  onclick="getPDFpath()">Tut02_v2-Ans</a>        
<p><a href="PDFJS/pdfFile/DA_Chap02_v3.pdf"  onClick="getPDFpath()">DA_Chap02_v3</a>
```

I need to get link from anchor attribute using Javascript. Here is my javascript function.

```
function getPDFpath(){
    var path = document.getElementById('link');
    var s = path.getAttribute('a');
    alert(s.href);  
}
```

Need link after pressing click. 
Thank you

Comment: where did you provide Id `link` in your markup?

Comment: the a element contain in a DIV defined as link

Comment: Consider marking a post as "Answer" if you consider it as your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the link reference to the `getPDFpath` function.

```
<a href="PDFJS/pdfFile/DA_Chap02_v3.pdf"  onClick="getPDFpath(this)">DA_Chap02_v3</a>
```

You can now access the `href` property of the element.

```
function getPDFpath(link){
    //navigate to another page by passing the href as the `pdflink` query param.
    location.href = 'my_other_page.html?pdflink=' + encodeURIComponent(link.href);
}
```

However, you don't have to use any javascript code to do this:

```
<a href="my_other_page.html?pdflink=PDFJS/pdfFile/DA_Chap02_v3.pdf">DA_Chap02_v3</a>
```

Comment: thank your plalx! and how can i pass the link to another page using cookies?

Comment: @user2279850, Not sure I understand or if you are going in the right direction with cookies. Could you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: i want to pass the href path to another page that contain a iframe , and the iframe contain a js file

Comment: @user2279850, do you wish to navigate to that other page at the same time? If that's the case you could simply pass the `href` as a `url` parameter.

Comment: yes, i need to navigate to other page
in fact, i want to pass the href as a var to the iframe JS file which in other page i want to navigate

Comment: @user2279850, I have updated the answer, that should cover anything you asked. If you do not know what a query string parameter is, you should go read about it ;)

Comment: @plaix `onClick="getPDFpath(this)"` bad practice.

Comment: @b1-, have you read the entire answer? It's there for educationnal purposes and it worths nothing to change all the OP's code when answering a question. That would just make things even more obscure to them.

Comment: btw thank your @plalx the code is work and the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Here are functions to set and get cookies.

```
function setCookie(key, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    value = escape(value) + ((exdays === undefined) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = key + "=" + value + '; path=/';
}

function getCookie(key) {
    var i, x, y,
        ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x == key) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```